# Can I save the image

Tags: java, jsp, image-processing

I have coded a JSP that will show the image on the browser.

But I also want to save this image in the server-side.

I have searched the answer but I still don't know how to save.

What should I code in order to save output image?

```
<%@ page import="java.awt.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.awt.image.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.*" %>
<%
   Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
   java.sql.Connection connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/clothes","root","clothes");
   Statement statement0 = connection.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = statement0.executeQuery("select * from clothes");

   int i= 20;
   BufferedImage Image = new BufferedImage(600,380, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
   Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) Image.getGraphics();

   while(rs.next()) { 
        String Product = rs.getString("clothes_name");
        graphics.setColor(Color.white);
        graphics.drawString( Product ,15,i);        
        int Stock = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Sales Record"));
        if ( Stock >= 25 ) graphics.setColor(Color.green);
        if ( Stock >= 15 && Stock < 25  ) graphics.setColor(Color.yellow);
        if ( Stock < 15  ) graphics.setColor(Color.red);
        graphics.fillRect( 20,i+5, (Stock*10), 10);        
        i=i+30;
   }
    rs.close();
    connection.close();
    response.reset();
    ServletOutputStream OutStream = response.getOutputStream();
    JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(OutStream);
    encoder.encode(Image);
    //I want to save this image, how to do so?
    OutStream.close();
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use much of the same code. You just need to replace

```
ServletOutputStream OutStream = response.getOutputStream();
```

by

```
OutputStream OutStream = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/file.jpg");
```

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, please note that [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367) state that variable names ought to start with lowercase. Also note that doing this in a JSP file instead of a Java class is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) the best practice. It makes the Java code unreuseable by normal Java classes.